# Having Error after deploying Django in Heroku. LookupError

Tags: django, heroku, nltk

I just deployed my sentiment analysis django app to heroku. The deployment was successful and I can access the features like login register etc. But I am unable to analyze the text because apparently, nltk cannot be found. But I have installed and imported it in my local host and it already worked before.

This is my first time deploying in heroku so I am unfamiliar with everything.

This is how it looks in my local host:
[image]

This is the error in the herokuapp live webapp when I try to analyze the sentiment.

```
    LookupError at /sentiment/type/
**********************************************************************
  Resource e[93mpunkte[0m not found.
  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:

  e[31m>>> import nltk
  >>> nltk.download('punkt')
  e[0m
  For more information see: https://www.nltk.org/data.html

  Attempted to load e[93mtokenizers/punkt/PY3/english.picklee[0m

  Searched in:
    - '/app/nltk_data'
    - '/app/.heroku/python/nltk_data'
    - '/app/.heroku/python/share/nltk_data'
    - '/app/.heroku/python/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data'
    - ''
**********************************************************************
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    https://sentymeter.herokuapp.com/sentiment/type/
Django Version: 4.0
Exception Type: LookupError
Exception Value:    
**********************************************************************
  Resource e[93mpunkte[0m not found.
  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:

  e[31m>>> import nltk
  >>> nltk.download('punkt')
  e[0m
  For more information see: https://www.nltk.org/data.html

  Attempted to load e[93mtokenizers/punkt/PY3/english.picklee[0m

  Searched in:
    - '/app/nltk_data'
    - '/app/.heroku/python/nltk_data'
    - '/app/.heroku/python/share/nltk_data'
    - '/app/.heroku/python/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data'
    - ''
**********************************************************************
Exception Location: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/data.py, line 583, in find
Python Executable:  /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
Python Version: 3.8.9
Python Path:    
['/app/.heroku/python/bin',
 '/app',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python38.zip',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 05 Jan 2022 20:16:57 +0000
```

setting.py

```
    """
Django settings for sentiment_emotion_analysis project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.1.7.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/
"""


import os
# os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "sentiment.settings")

# import django
# django.setup()

# from django.core.management import call_command

from django.contrib.messages import constants as messages
MESSAGE_TAGS = {
        messages.DEBUG: 'alert-debug',
        messages.INFO: 'alert-info',
        messages.SUCCESS: 'success',
        messages.WARNING: 'alert-warning',
        messages.ERROR: 'danger',
}


# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'g&x!0fjh8c8)e_-z@gs1^lbngvqwk2(o3s(5zg!o&woxdsu_un'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['sentymeter.herokuapp.com' , '127.0.0.1']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'sentiment',
    'user',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
   
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'sentiment_emotion_analysis.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'sentiment_emotion_analysis.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static')

MODELS = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'sentiment/models')
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you installed the nltk python package but not any data for it.

If you want a quick fix, you can connect to your heroku (`heroku ps:exec` ) and run a django shell `python manage.py shell` and then install the relevant nltk modules from the python shell:

```
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
```

Since you want to be able to redeploy it, better create a [management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-management-commands/) to do this and run it similar to how you run migrations. Management command should be under `{app}/management/commands/`

A command like this:

```py
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Install NLTK stuff'
   
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        import nltk
        nltk.download(..) # replace the dots with the relevant corpora
```

Comment: I tried the second method but and already pushed the commit to github but when I tried to redeployed it in heroku, I received this error

`-----> Downloading NLTK corpora…
 !     'nltk.txt' not found, not downloading any corpora
 !     Learn more: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-nltk
-----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
      `

Comment: Then I tried to add the nltk.txt and added punkt n got this error
`-----> Downloading NLTK corpora…
-----> Downloading NLTK packages: punkt
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/runpy.py:127: RuntimeWarning: 'nltk.downloader' found in sys.modules after import of package 'nltk', but prior to execution of 'nltk.downloader'; this may result in unpredictable behaviour
  warn(RuntimeWarning(msg))
[nltk_data] Downloading package punkt to
[nltk_data]     /tmp/build_6f3f8e9f/.heroku/python/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Unzipping tokenizers/punkt.zip.
-----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput`

Comment: But the first method you gave did work, so I guess I'm just gonna stick with that. Thank you so much for helping me out :)

Comment: yeah, you should replace the 2 dots with the nltk corpora you want to install, I guess `punkt` in your case

Comment: I have a question, if I close my laptop or maybe close the shell where I downloaded the packages, will the installed packed be gone? Because I put my laptop on sleep for a while and the same error happens again. When I turned on my laptop, I see this on the shell `Connection to the dyno timed out!`.  But after I reinstalled bac everything like the steps u mentioned, everything is back to normal. But will it happen again if I close my laptop?

Comment: Also, can you elaborate on how to run the second method, Im not very familiar with migrations so I don't know how to run it.

Comment: Your laptop does not impact dyno - so no, you don't need to run anything. I posted a link to mgmt command. I assume at some point you are running `python manage.py migrate` so the new command should come before/after,